# KafkaStreams: Handling Deserialize exception in KStream-KTable Join

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Let say we are doing a inner join between a KStream and KTable as shown below:

```
        StreamsBuilder sb = new StreamsBuilder();
        JsonSerde<SensorMetaData> sensorMetaDataJsonSerde = new JsonSerde<>(SensorMetaData.class);
        KTable<String, String> kTable = sb.stream("sensorMetadata",
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), sensorMetaDataJsonSerde)).toTable();

        KStream<String, String> kStream = sb.stream("sensorValues",
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        KStream<String, String> joined = kStream.join(kTable, (left, right)->{return getJoinedOutput(left, right);});
```

Few points about the application:

1. SensorMetaData is a POJO

   ```
       public class SensorMetaData{        
       String sensorId;
       String sensorMetadata;      
       }
   ```
2. DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG is set to org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
3. JsonSerde class will throw SerializationException if Deserialization fails.

When i run the application and send messages to both the topics, join works as expected.

Now i changed the schema of SensorMetaData as below and redeployed the application on a new node

```
public class SensorMetaData{            
String sensorId;    
MetadataTag[] metadataTags;         
}
```

After the application starts, when iam sending a message to sensorValues topic( streams topic), the application is shutting down with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException. Looking at the stack trace, i realized its failing to deserialize SensorMetaData while performing join because of the schema change in SensorMetaData. Break point in Deserialize method shows, its trying to deserialize data from the topic "app-KSTREAM-TOTABLE-STATE-STORE-0000000002-changelog".

So the question is why is the application shutting down instead of skipping the bad record (i.e. the record with old schema) even though,  DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG is set to org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler ?

However, when application encounters bad record while reading from the topic "sensorMetadata" (i.e. sb.stream("sensorMetadata")), it successfully skips the record with warning "Skipping record due to deserialization error".

Why join is not skipping the bad record here ? How to handle this scenario. I want the application to skip the record and continue running instead of shutting down. Here is the stack trace

```
at kafkastream.JsonSerde$2.deserialize(JsonSerde.java:51)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.deserialize(ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.deserialize(ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.outerValue(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:207)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$get$2(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:821)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.get(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl$KeyValueStoreReadWriteDecorator.get(ProcessorContextImpl.java:465)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableSourceValueGetterSupplier$KTableSourceValueGetter.get(KTableSourceValueGetterSupplier.java:49)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKTableJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKTableJoinProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$3(StreamTask.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:475)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)
INFO stream-client [app-814c1c5b-a899-4cbf-8d85-2ed6eba81ccb] State transition from ERROR to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka doesn't use the handler in `DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG` when it reads the RocksDB files (see that the stacktrace mentions the class `StateSerdes`). That's why it works fine for records coming from the source topic, but fails when deserialising the data in the table.

I'm not super experienced with Kafka, but I keep hearing over and over again: if something changes, copy the data with the new format to another topic or delete the data, reset offsets and re-process.

In this case, maybe it's better to delete the KTable files, the internal topics used for the ktable and let the app re-generate the KTable with the new structure.

This blog from a few months ago explains a bit more the process or deleting data: https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/

To share a bit of insight: kafka is a very complex beast. To manage it successfuly in production you need to build a good amount of tooling, code to maintain it, and (usually) change your deployment process to fit Kafka.